# PHP data not being received by database

Tags: php, sql, derby, netbeans-8

I run this code, and it does not add data to the table. (Also I get no errors).

I think perhaps in someway it can't be sending the data to the table, is there a way to check whats happening in that regard or what do you guys think I should do to narrow down the problem?

I am using netbeans 8 if thats relevant.

```
<?php
        $servername="localhost";
        $username="test";
        $password="";

        $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

        if (!$mysqli){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo 'Connected successfully';

        $sql = ("INSERT INTO test_table (column_test) VALUES ('boo')");

        ?>
```

Comment: doesnt look like you're actually sending that data to a sql server. just putting a string in quotes and parenthesis does nothing. you should probably [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) a little...

Comment: use google it's very basic question -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score -2):

You need to execute query, put code below under your $sql

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

Comment: Yes, the query needs to be executed, but OP is using mysqli.

Comment: Ahh execute query.. I just started this yesterday, thanks for putting me on the right track  C: